Options for nonreflective black surfaces for macro
I am shooting large format macro images. I currently use some velvet as the surface. The velvet is not quite non-reflective;  the little hairs reflect some light. Generally I am shooting down; subjects are things like small sea shells.
Creating little stands to hold small objects a bit off the surface is possible, but fiddly. Are there other commonly-available materials that less reflective than velvet?
It is also possible that I left the fabric store with inferior quality velvet, I suppose, so the answer might be to get a higher quality. Obviously, repair in post is also an option, but I try to avoid extensive post work when I can.


Black velvet is pretty much the best choice. Perhaps purchasing some  higher quality fabric?

Another thing to consider is distance - rather than having the subject resting on or directly near the background, move the background a distance away. That might increase the challenges around how to mount/position the subject, but it will help reduce reflections.

Musou black fabric is some of the most light absorbing available... about 99.9% for the Kiwami


In the photo, it looks like blocks the light that passes thru it. A curtain. But is it less reflective in general?

@Rafael, that wasn't a great reference/link, so I edited my response with a better product.

You can also coat a matte black paper with Musou black matte paint. Although the fabric is probably more practical.

I have not tested it but could be an option.
Get some acrylic black paint you can afford in your locality. https://www.google.com/search?q=blackest+paint
There are some interesting options.
If you can, try to spray paint for a more uniform look. Im sure they can even used on a fabric.

Glass
Ok, to be fair, glass can be pretty reflective. But it’s not when you are looking straight down onto it like you describe, which means it is perfect.
Below the glass, put a hole into box, painted black on the inside, with just any generic black really, but you could use something like black 3.0 if you worry about any light being reflected, not just a very dark and featureless background. Because the glass is elevating above that surface, that black won’t be in focus so any surface patterns that are reflecting light, will be effectively invisible.

This could work in particular cases.

But it’s not when you are looking straight down onto it  - there is no such law of physics.

@EuriPinhollow "there is no such law of physics." I'm not sure what you mean, glass has quite low reflectivity when viewed from low angles of incidence, not zero but quite low. It also is a flat surface so it wont leave artifacts like the ones felt did in the OP, its not a law of physics its just a property of glass.

And also, the reflection of glass isn’t diffuse, if your light source is offset even just a little from your camera, it won’t see any of the (small) reflection.

low reflectivity when viewed from low angles of incidence - why don't you compare that with having black background being the worst case for avoiding reflections?
